# Problem in building flutter projects in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build Flutter Projects in Android Studio. But the process takes a lot of time and the project does not build. I keep getting following messages in the console-

**Launching lib\main.dart on SM M215F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...**

There are no errors in any file and the usb debugging is enabled in my phone. Please help!
[image]

Can anybody tell if the problem is due to the following problems in project structure-
[image]

Comment: You can run using terminal `flutter run -v` to see the log process.

Comment: I am getting following message in the console (stuck here)-[+1801 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.7!
[        ] Here are the highlights of this release:
[        ]  - File system watching is ready for production use
[        ]  - Declare the version of Java your build requires
[        ]  - Java 15 support
[        ] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comment, you can do a verbose run to see if/where it gets stuck. You can also do this while running in Android Studio, by clicking on `Edit Configurations...` at the top of the screen:

[image]

And then under `Additional run args:` putting `-v` to run in verbose mode.

Comment: I tried to build it again after enabling verbose, I am getting following messages in last- [+1801 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.7!
[        ] Here are the highlights of this release:
[        ]  - File system watching is ready for production use
[        ]  - Declare the version of Java your build requires
[        ]  - Java 15 support
[        ] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html

Comment: If I were you I'd try using a different version of Gradle, or a different Java version, just to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: I have also tried running the project in VS Code but stuck at -                                                   Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the `stable` channel? Does `flutter doctor -v` report anything wrong?

Comment: This is the message I get when I run flutter channel -v command in Android Studio-[ +226 ms] Flutter channels:
[   +2 ms] executing: [D:\flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable\flutter/] git branch -r
[ +135 ms]   master
[   +1 ms]   dev
[        ]   beta
[        ] * stable
[  +46 ms] "flutter channel" took 772ms.
[ +295 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 287ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +6 ms] exiting with code 0
PS D:\quiztime>

Comment: No problem detected using flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

This task usually takes a very long time and it will be even longer if you have a slower laptop. However, once you get past it, it will become much faster when using hot reload. If flutter doctor doesn't report anything unusual then maybe give it some more time.

Comment: It was working fine earlier but for the projects that I built today, it is taking a lot of time. I see no progress even after leaving it for an hour. (I am using a new laptop powered by core i5 11th gen processor).

Comment: I see you are on on windows, disable the firewall temporarily. For some people reinstalling Dart works. You can try `gradle build --profile` to check what's taking up so long.